# Why I use pointer's pointer to maintain a two-dimensional array but caught a segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C (and also programming). Recently I practise a lot in leetcode(oj.leetcode.com) by using C. While I was coding below problem:

http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string/

It means if the input is "the sky is blue", the output should be "blue is sky the". I decided to use two-dimensional char array to store the words and print them in reversed order. Here is the code:

```
void reversed(char s[]) {
int wordcount=0;
char** words;
int i=0;


for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
{
    if(!isspace(s[i]))
    {
        **words=s[i];
        *words++;
    }
    else
    {
        **words='\0';
        wordcount++;
        words++;
    }
}
for(;wordcount=0;wordcount--,words--)
{

    printf("%s", *words);
    printf(" ");
}
printf("\n");
```

But I encountered a segmentation fault, here is the GDB info:

```
23  for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
(gdb) n
25                      if(!isspace(s[i]))
(gdb) n
27                              **words=s[i];
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401226 in reversewords (s=0x22abe0 "the sky is blue") at reversewords.c:27
27                              **words=s[i];
```

Can anybody can help me to figure out what's going on here and how to correct my code to make it work? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to allocate the array

Comment: To get the individual words, `strtok` is worth a peek!

Comment: Your for-loop to print the words should use `wordcount==0`. Currently, it is assigning 0 to wordcount instead of testing if it is 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you've done here is that take a pointer to pointer to character and then started working with it.

**Why is it wrong ?**

You have a pointer (or more precisely pointer to pointer) to char, but you never told it where to point to. Right now for all we know, it is pointing to some memory that you are not supposed to point to, or maybe some other junk memory location.

**What do we do?**

Use malloc, allocate memory to your pointer and then use it.

Keep in mind that when you have pointer to pointer to character, you'll have to `malloc` twice. The first one will make your pointer point to the placeholders for pointers that will point to characters.  (Read again, it might make sense :P )

ie. if I do

```
char *ptr;
```

In this case, I'll do

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10)  //considering your words are max length 10.
```

But since you want multiple words, hence you want a pointer that will point to an array of such pointers.

```
char **ptrSuper
ptrSuper = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 4) // considering you have 4 words.
```

Overall, this is what you'll have to do

```
char **ptr
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 4)
for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*10)
```

So I searched for one minute, and I found the following pic from some source that will make it a bit more lucid.

[Link for Image.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/pointertopointer/ptr_to_ptr.jpg)

---

As mentioned in the comments below, You don't need to do allocation for each word that you are to reverse. Since you'll get the reference of that from the character array you are passing. But just in case.

Comment: so I need to `free` them in the reversed order,right? just like `for(j=0;j<20;j++)
  free(words[j]);
   
 free(words);`

Comment: It works in my code. Thank you. But when I ran it, I got a "aborted (core dump)" Do you know why that happend?

Comment: OP's solution doesn't need allocations for `ptr[idx]` because his words are actually pointing inside string. (Already existing string buffer)

Comment: @MohitJain Aah, did not see that. My bad.

Comment: @behumble I am sorry, but I guess you don't need to do malloc for individual words. As Mohit mentioned in the above comment. As for your aborted(core dump). You know what? This will be a nice exercise for you to understand how all these work. Don't ask for a straightaway question here, instead debug the code and see what went wrong. This will be a bit hectic but well worth the time.

Comment: @behumble And to be completely honest, I am not sure why you are getting core dump. :P

Comment: @behumble But if I were to guess, it would be something to do with bad memory access. Could be that something is not initialised or some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate space for your array. This is usually done using `malloc`:

```
// dynamically allocated array of 10 ints
int* dynamicIntArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

The problem here is that you don't know the number of elements beforehand. The general solution is to allocate a certain amount of space, and then reallocate more in case it is not sufficient (using `realloc`, for example). So your flow becomes:

1. Allocate some initial space using an arbitrary starting size: 
   `char** words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);`
2. Every time you add something to the array, check if you already have 100 elements. If so: 
   `words = realloc(words, lastSize * 2);`
3. When you're done, free the memory: `free(words);`

**Some notes**

1. You **mustn't** increment `words` for the `free` to work correctly. So you have to either use a second pointer (`char** pWords = words;` then: `pWords++`) or use numeric indices instead of pointer arithmetic.
2. Allocating twice the original buffer's size is a common heuristic to keep the number of reallocations small.
3. In your case, you could in principle determine the number of words beforehand by counting spaces, but then you'll need to go over the input string twice.

As a side note: If all this seems daunting, keep in mind you don't have to handle this complexity when working in more high-level languages. In C++ for example, you can use a `std::vector` which will automatically grow as you add elements, and automatically free it's memory.